# transformation of binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

First, apologies if this is answered elsewhere and I've just not managed to search it properly.

If I have a discrete random variable $X$ that follows the binomial distribution, then what distribution does $\frac{1}{X}$ have? In particular, I'd like to understand the expected value and variance. I've tried calculating these by hand and have gotten stuck.

Is this a well-studied distribution? Is there a special name for it, or something I could search to learn more about it? Someone suggested to me that it's the negative (aka inverse) binomial distribution, but I can't get the details to work out, so I think it's something else.

Thanks!

EDIT: As Henry pointed out, a binomial distribution has a nontrivial chance of being 0. For my particular application of this, it's very natural to omit these from the domain, but I suppose then it's not a strict binomial distribution.

Comment: A binomial distribution can take the value $0$ with positive probability $(1-p)^n$, so you have problems with its reciprocal

Comment: Very true. I'm not worried about it in my case because there's a very natural way to restrict the domain to only cases where X > 0; I guess that means it's not a strict binomial distribution, though. Thanks, I'll update the question.